# Put 3 canvases on a page, side-by-side

Tags: html, canvas

I need to put more than one (3) HTML5 Canvas side by side.  Left and right will be 200px wide.  Center will fill the rest of the space.  All three need to fill the screen vertically.

What I'm doing is building a drawing program.  Left and right will be drawing tools. Center will be the drawing area.  I think I need a canvas specifically for the drawing area in order to zoom, pan, scroll the drawing without the image overlapping the tool windows.  Essentially I'm using the center canvas as a clipping range.  I don't know if this is the best way to do this or not.

What I've tried is putting 3 `<canvas>`es on the screen, but they just overlap.  I put 3 in `<div>`s, but they just stack.

Thoughts?

Comment: Three canvases shouldn’t overlap. Are you applying any CSS that might affect them?

Comment: I wouldn't think so either.  I have no CSS at all on the page.  What I did was to put a background color on each so I could see them.  only one shows up.  When i put them in divs then all showed up fine, just stacked.

Comment: … did you remember to use the closing `</canvas>` tag?

Comment: THANKS!  I was using <canvas ... />  not <canvas ...></canvas>  That worked.

Comment: how do i mark a comment as an answer???  Mini, can you put in answer so I can mark it???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comments, `<canvas>` isn’t a void tag, so you need to write `</canvas>`.

You can also use that to provide helpful text in case somebody’s browsing in something not-quite-modern:

```
<canvas id="one">
    Hey, your browser doesn’t support the Canvas API!
    You should upgrade if you want to use this.
</canvas>
```

Comment: One small additional question.  Keeping them all inline when the browser changes size?  I'm assuming display:inline in a style tag, but applied to what?

Comment: @Cuthahotha: You could put them in a container `<div>` and give that container `white-space: nowrap`.